# Can't center a div Bootstrap4/Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, jsfiddle

I am trying to make my application more beautiful thanks to Bootstrap,

I am currently trying to center a "[card](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/)" from Bootstrap

I found a way to do it with [mx-auto](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

My code with mx-auto only works in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb7wqz9r/23/)

```
<div class="card text-white bg-info mx-auto" style="max-width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-header">Header</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Info card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the     card's content.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But in my application the card is not centered, does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

*The bootstrap version I embedded to my Angular project is 4.1.2*

Here is the way I embedded Bootstrap to my angular project :

I used

1. npm install bootstrap --save
2. npm install jquery --save
3. npm install popper.js --save

Then i added to my angular.json
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" to the styles

And

- "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" to the styles
- "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" to the scripts
- "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js" to the scripts
- "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" to the scripts

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use a row and column with the class `justify-content-center`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="card text-white bg-info">
        <div class="card-header">Header</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Info card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the     card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code make my "card" moves a bit to the right but not enough to  get centered

Comment: It feels like you have some kind of parent element with fixed width in your app. Could this be the case? The parent element of the card needs to use up 100% of the screen width.

Comment: I am quite a novice to css, do you know which element could be the parent of card ? 
I don't if it's could be the problem because i am currently just trying to display a centered card, nothing more

Comment: If you view the source code of the page in your browser, you can check if the card is placed in a parent element. Then you can inspect it to see if it has a fixed width. For example it could be a <div> or a <body> tag that limits the width of your app.

Comment: When i try to display simple text, it start at the same position my card is displayed, between the left margin and the middle of the page

Comment: Is there anyway we can see the html source code of your app? Have you checked for parent elements with fixed width or anyting else that narrows the width of your page?

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap 4, you have inbuild CSS 'text-center' so, you can use it on any div class to center the content

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="card text-white bg-info mx-auto text-center" style="max-width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-header">Header</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title text-center">Info card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the     card's content.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but i am trying to center the card, not the content of the card

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to include one of required  files. Do you have all of these?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```